# Avoiding hardcode aws role on circleCi config.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, circleci

I have below circleCi config.yml file where the value of role-arn is hardcode

```yaml
orbs:
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@3.1.4
jobs:
  aws-cli-example:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/python:3.11.0-node
    working_directory: ~/workspace
    environment:
      AWS_REGION: 'us-east-1'
    executor: aws-cli/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - aws-cli/setup:
          role-arn: 'arn:aws:I am::<aws_account_id>:role/circleci_role'
      - run:
         name: CDK deployment in AWS
         command: |
           chmod +x .circleci/script1.sh
           source .circleci/script1.sh
workflows:
  aws-cli:
    jobs:
      - aws-cli-example:
          context: credentials
```

I do not want to hardcode that role on this script instead I would like it to be used as an env variable. How can I accomplish that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Go to your circleci project settings, then select environment variables, and add your arn or aws specific secrets.
Then use in aws like this -

```
orbs:
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@3.1.3

jobs:
  build-n-check: 
    executor: aws-cli/default
    docker:
      - image: cimg/deploy:2022.11
    
    working_directory: ~/project

    steps:
      - checkout

      - aws-cli/setup:
          aws-access-key-id: aws_access_key_id
          aws-secret-access-key: aws_secret_access_key
          aws-region: region
```

In that case I saved acces keys in circleci env variables.

In your case, if you save your arn by the name ARN -

```
role-arn: ARN
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The objective of using a role is to avoid hard-coded credentials

Comment: I think $ARN will do it instead of ARN

Comment: Not actually. I have pasted my working code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue is to use a role . Your job in circleCi is the client trying to authenticate to the Authorization Service (CircleCi) to deploy services into AWS(Identity Provider).

As such you need to get a role from the identity Provider(AWS). Your security team or admin or someone whith enough privilege should set up an AWS WebIdentity Provider for CircleCi and from that for your specific CircleCi job you should get a role with permissions to deploy the services you want. They should provide the role to you

then you use the role in your circleCi job(client)